# Omega Limit sets for a Gradient system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to do the following exercise

> Let $V: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function such that the set of equilibrium points is finite. Consider the diferential equation $x'=-\nabla V(x)$. Show that $V$ has no periodic orbits and no homoclinic orbits, and that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if we have that $\omega(x)\neq \emptyset$ then it consists of a single equilibrium point.

The first two assertions I was able to do. The first by noticing that $V(x(t_0))-V(x(t_N))=\int_{t_0}^{t_N}\frac{d}{ds}V(x(s)) ds =\int_{t_0}^{t_N}-\nabla V(x(s))^2ds<0$.

The second one since we have that $\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))<0$ for any solution starting in the homoclinic orbit and if we have that $x_0$ is the equilibrium point associated with the homoclinic orbit then $x_0=\lim_{t_n\rightarrow \infty}x(t_n)=\lim_{t_n\rightarrow -\infty}x(t_n)$ but since we have that $V(x(t))$ is decreasing with time we get that $V(x_0)< V(x(t_0))<V(x_0)$ and hence a contradiction .

Now the one I am not being able to do is the third assertion . Let's suppose that $\omega(x)\neq \emptyset $, and now I would like to see that for $y\in \omega(x)$ then $\nabla V(y)=0$, and with this I would get that $\omega(x)$ is a compact set since there's a finite number of equilibrium points and hence connceted and so it can only be one. But I am not sure how to see that $\nabla V(y)=0$ . We have that $\nabla V(y)=\lim_{t_n\rightarrow \infty}\nabla  V(x(t_n))$.

Also another idea would be to try and use Poincare Bendixson theorem but I am not sure that $\omega(x)\neq \emptyset$ implies that it is bounded, since there are examples of unbounded $\omega$-limit sets.

Also I don't think we know that the solution is defined on the whole line but I guess we are assuming it, I think for this to be true could ask that $V(x)\geq 0$ and that $V(0)=0.$

Any help with this last is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i ask you what book you are studying from?

Comment: Mostly from Perko , but this is an exercise from an old exam of the course I am taking.@LordCommander